# if/else statement from a DOM object

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am trying to get an if/else statement to work, however I am missing something.

From my API I am pulled an JSON object "entity id" and the state of that id "state".

Creating the entity state:

```
var $$ = Dom7;

 $$('[entity-status="' + entity.entity_id + '"]').html(entity.state);
```

The code above can be used within my HTML and will display the state correctly.
 `<div entity-status='switch.office_light_2'></div>` the DIV will display `ON`

When I try to use it in an if/else statement it dose not work.

```
if ($("entity-status='switch.office_light_2'") === "ON") {
    document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = "Success";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = "nope";

    }
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: That means `$("entity-status='switch.office_light_2'")` must not be exactly equal to "ON". Have you checked what it actually is?

Comment: What is `$` in your code? Why would `$("entity-status='switch.office_light_2'")` return `ON` ?

Comment: when i place `entity-status='switch.office_light_2'` in to a div the div ends up displaying the "ON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select div with attribute, you can use:

```
$("div[entity-status='switch.office_light_2']")
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#bn_Switch', function() {
  //attribute selector
  var statusDiv = $("div[entity-status='switch.office_light_2']");
  //getting current text of div to change the status
  var statusText = statusDiv.text() == "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
  $(statusDiv).text(statusText);
  //checking with the changed text to update 'live' div
  document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = (statusDiv.text() == "ON" ? "Success" : "nope");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div entity-status='switch.office_light_2'>
</div>

<input id="bn_Switch" type="submit" value="Click" />

<div id='live'>
</div>
```